Underfull hbox in amsaddr footer with long email addresses
When using \usepackage[foot]{amsaddr} for author information along with long email addresses, typesetting results in an Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) warning. Here is the document I am typsetting (using pdfLaTeX from Tex Live 2023).
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

\title{Title}

\email{an.email@addr.com}
\email{another.email@example.com}
\email{a.third.email@domain.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}

How can I fix this warning?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

You can use \raggedright when typesetting the email addresses.
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

%% Use \raggedright to typeset email addresses
\AddToHook{cmd/@setemails/before}{\raggedright}


\title{Title}
\author{1}
\email{an.email@addr.com}
\author{2}
\email{another.email@example.com}
\author{3}
\email{a.third.email@domain.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}



You can tell that next email address should be at next line using the \puttonextline macro which can be used before email address.
\documentclass{amsart}

\def\puttonextline{\egroup\hfil\break\hbox\bgroup}

\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

\title{Title}

\email{an.email@addr.com}
\email{another.email@example.com}
\email{\puttonextline a.third.email@domain.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}

